# Is it better to think of electron shells as depending on the value of $n$, or depending on the energy difference between sub-shells?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, hydrogen, orbitals, spherical-harmonics

Often electron shells are defined as 'states with the same principal quantum number $n$' which would suggest that $3s$, $3p$, $3d$ sub-shells are all in the same shell.

Conversely, it is also often said that Argon has a 'full electron shell' when really it has full $3s$ and $3p$ sub-shells but not $3d$. However one could argue this makes more sense to define as 'a shell' since the $4s$ sub-shell is occupied before the $3d$ sub-shell, and the reason why Argon is inert in the first place is since there is a significant energy level difference between $3p$ and $4s$.

My question is, should 'electron shells' be considered as groups of sub-shells with similar energies (before some significant energy level 'jump') and *not* as simply shells with the same principal quantum number $n$?

My question is *not* about the effect of multi-electron atoms affecting the energy levels, I'm purely asking which definition of 'shell' is more common. Should I interpret the 'principal quantum number $n$ definition' as dodgy or the 'Argon has a full electron shell' statement as dodgy?

Comment: I believe "full shell" is generally taken to refer only to the s and p sub-shells